# How to use a reverse proxy to split traffic between containers based on URL

Tags: networking, proxy, docker, reverse-proxy

I'm on a residential network (behind a NAT), and want to host multiple services in containers on a server.

Since they all use the same internal ports (and it is very difficult to change them), I was wondering if it was possible to use a reverse proxy to split the traffic between the containers based on the target URL.

I know that this is possible for HTTP services, but I'm not sure how to do this for generic TCP connections.

Additionally this would allow me to separate each service into its own domain and related container, without worrying about port collisions.

Comment: While not a load-balancing solution, most NAT routers will allow you to configure the port mapping between external and internal ports.  So you could have several ports open on the external side, being forwarded to the same port on different IPs internally.  This would allow you to connect to those services, without having to change the ports on the containers.

Comment: @heavyd unfortunately what I want to do is kind of the opposite. I want to forward essentially all traffic on all ports to a single server, and for users to use `service1.host.com` and `service2.host.com` to send that traffic into different servers within that. I think that I need to get multiple user facing ip addresses for this to work unfortunately...

Comment: Yes, then I think @user1686 pretty much has your answer. With raw TCP, there is no way to distinguish the traffic.  You need a higher level protocol like HTTP or TLS that carries that DNS name to be able to do that splitting.

Comment: @heavyd There seems to be an option with cloudflare to tunnel everything via their network, which may allow this approach. If I get it working I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is nothing in TCP that would indicate which domain name (much less which URL) was originally requested; only the peers' IP addresses and TCP ports are known.

So this is only possible if you have a higher-layer protocol that provides the necessary information (much like HTTP does in its 'Host' header), and the proxy must understand that higher-layer protocol. Generic TCP multiplexing based on domain name is not possible.

For example, if all your services use TLS, then you could multiplex based on the domain name sent in the TLS SNI extension (and possibly even the protocol type sent in TLS ALPN) – this can be done using HAproxy, sniproxy, or possibly even Nginx.

(There are also specialized proxies which can multiplex different protocols based on the recognized client handshake – e.g. 'sshttp' can deal with SSH & HTTP on the same port, similarly 'sslh' does SSH & TLS. All such proxies need at least basic understanding of all protocols involved, and they only work reliably with protocols where the client speaks first.)

Comment: I suspected that this may be the case, since what I wanted would constitute a layer violation...